# .push commant executes "Underfind" from jquery function, how to execute a number?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

So the script is really simple, I try to `push` the dNumber into variable `pattern` and the results are always "underfined". 
when i try to do the same with just push a TEXT for example it's worked.

```js
var level = 0;
var pattern = [];
var userPatern = [];

function dNumber() {
  var a = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100 / 25) + 1);
  console.log(a);
  console.log(pattern);
}

$("body").click(gamestart);
$("body").keypress(gamestart);

function gamestart() {
  $("#level-title").text("level " + level);
  var x = dNumber();
  pattern.push(x);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```js
var level = 0;
var pattern = [];
var userPatern = [];
function dNumber(){
  var a = Math.floor((Math.random()*100/25)+1);
  console.log(a);
  console.log(pattern);
}
$("body").click(gamestart);
$("body").keypress(gamestart);
function gamestart() {
  $("#level-title").text("level " + level);
  var x = dNumber();
//  pattern.push("alex"); this is work!
pattern.push(x);
pattern.push(dNumber());
//this isn't work what should be number looks like appear as underfined.
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return a from `dNumber` function so that you can use :)

```js
var level = 0;
var pattern = [];
var userPatern = [];

function dNumber() {
  var a = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100 / 25) + 1);
  console.log(a);
  console.log(pattern);
  // return a here if not then it's gonna return undefined by default :)
  return a;
}

$("body").click(gamestart);
$("body").keypress(gamestart);

function gamestart() {
  $("#level-title").text("level " + level);
  var x = dNumber();
  pattern.push(x);
  console.log(pattern);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Halil thank you so much probably i miss it. i already saw few time a documentation where the hell i make a mistake and like always the answer is pretty simple. ahh man thank you so much!

Comment: Yea Sure it's always hard to pinpoint easy mistakes  and always nice to have an extra peer of eye on =)